# Access ADLS2 from PowerBI service with Guest user credentials

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-data-lake, powerbi-embedded, azure-data-lake-gen2

I've tried to give access to an Active Directory external user (with Guest type). ADLS2 enables to use of such users for RBAC or ACL tables.

But when I tried to access ADLS2 as a guest user from the Power BI service I've got an error:
"The credentials provided for the AzureDataLakeStorage source are invalid.":

```
Failed to update data source credentials: The credentials provided for the AzureDataLakeStorage source are invalid. (Source at https://hasodl2westeurope.dfs.core.windows.net/mycontainer/samplefolder.)
Hide details
Activity ID:    269cbc1b-c50a-4078-a408-6f64246d0a19
Request ID: caabe243-c75a-5507-1610-88cc41b19ae6
Status code:    400
Time:   Thu Jan 09 2020 12:27:37 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
Service version:    13.0.11747.315
Client version: 1912.2.031
Cluster URI:    https://wabi-west-europe-b-primary-redirect.analysis.windows.net/
```

Is this behavior a bug or a feature?

Is a way to access ALDS2 as a Guest user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADLS only supports AD users from the same tenant, not guest users - [source](https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues/984).